# DynamoDB Get distinct attributes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My DynamoDB table has the following structure:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+
|    to     |   from    |   medium   |  messageBody  | timestamp |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+
| 123456789 | 1234:4321 | somemedium | Hello World 1 |  23422523 |
| 123456789 | 9876:4321 | somemedium | Hello World 2 |  23432529 |
| 123456789 | 4565:3213 | somemedium | Hello World 3 |  23467839 |
| 123456789 | 4565:3323 | somemedium | Hello World 4 |  23533789 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+
```

My goal is to write a query that gives me back all distinct `from` attributes (no duplicates). The challenge here is that the whole attribute e.g. `1234:4321` will always be unique. However, what matters is the part before the `:`. So in my example, the expected result is as follows: `[1234, 9876, 4565]`. Is that even possible with DynamoDB or should I just get "all" attributes and do the other work with Python?

Answer (score -1):

If `from` is the partition key in the DynamoDB table, then you have to use only equal condition to fetch item. Since dynamoDB doesn't support <,>,substring etc in partition key.

For ex:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name='us-west-2')
table = dynamodb.Table('ddbtable')

response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('from').eq("1234:4321")
)
for item in response['Items']:
print(item['from'])
#substring etc...
```

Once you have the item, apply operation on it.